# java robot keypress does not work

Tags: java, awtrobot

so I'm facing a problem which is when I use this code :

#### code was updated

```
        int x = 530;
        int y = 135;
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.mouseMove(x, y);
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);          
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

the program types "test" in eclipse, and so I have done some search and found people with similar issues and after they have compiled it to jar it worked fine, and so that is what I did , but after compiling it, the mouse is moving fine but the program does not type anything.

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you select. That is not the correct `robot` tag.

Comment: sorry , wha is the right tag then ? @JonathonReinhart

Comment: tag updated. Where should the program be writing? Into what application?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you send the clicks and the keystrokes to, so I can't be sure what the problem is, but my guess as to why the code is not working as intended is that you never release the mouse button and the keys. `Robot.mousePress(int)` only presses the mouse button down, it doesn't release it, you'd have to call `Robot.mouseRelease(int)` (as stated in the documentation). The same applies to keystrokes. Also, `InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` is deprecated, the documentation recommends to use `InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` instead.

Comment: @Singy ok so I have updated the code but I am facing the same issue , I am trying to write in google chrome (right now trying to write in the stackoverflow search box) sometimes it write's one letter and sometimes it does nothing !

Comment: @keloa You also need to release the keys, not only the mouse button.